My Blazor Web App isn't reading any custom settings from appsettings.json
I placed a bunch of items in the "appsettings.json" file in my project.  Both at startup in Program.cs, and on any Razor component page where I inject IConfiguration, they all come back with null whenever I try to read any of the values I added to that file.  Any default values it will access, but any custom values (new or changed) it will not.
Why isn't IConfiguration reading from the appsettings or appsettings.Development files?

Are you reading the wrong appsettings.json?  Server/WASM/Auto?

In most Web App templates you have 2 Program.cs and 2 appsettings.json files. Specify which one you are talking about.

In the Client the file needs to be in the wwwroot folder, on the server it needs to be in the root of the application.

In the startup.cs you have to add initiate the IConfiguration class and call it in the Startup constructor
    public IConfiguration _Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(){
       _Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                   .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                   .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                   .Build();
     }

Verif the path of the appsettings.json it must be in the root of the project like the program.cs and startup.cs

Sorry, I have no idea what you mean - there is no "Startup.cs" - just "Program.cs" - and I have not been able to get it to read appsettings since I have started using .NET 8.  In my .NET 6 project it worked great.  But the precise description is that it will not read any custom settings - any "default" settings given by the system are read, but if I override those settings with new ones, or if I add new settings, these new values are not read.  I ended up making my own static class that explicitly reads the json file.
